# How to make a carousel not shake while scrolling and pause on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, carousel

The issue is every time `AnimateCarousel()` is called, the images jumps to the right a little in the slider before continuing. How can I prevent it?

Also, how can I pause on mouse over and continue on mouse out?

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    AnimateCarousel();
});

function AnimateCarousel() {
    console.log("test");
    var SD = 210;
    //var $carousel = $(that).parent();
    var $ul = $(".carousel").children('ul');
    var distance = SD;
    var time = 5500;
    var rate = distance / time;

    distance = Math.abs($ul.position().left);
    console.log(distance + " distance");
    if (distance != 0) {
        distance = SD - distance;

        time = distance / rate;
    }
    $ul.stop().animate({
        left: -210
    }, time, 'linear', function() {
        $ul.append($ul.children('li:first-child'));
        $ul.css({
            left: 0
        });
        AnimateCarousel();
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.carousel {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
}

.carousel ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.tst1 {
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.carousel li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel li:hover > div {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div>
        </li>

        <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/200x200" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the default margin between li is 4px I added this to the **.carousel li {** in the css so that anytime the first li is appended to the end this margin is respected.

Added: pause on mouse over and continue on mouse out.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  AnimateCarousel();

  $(".carousel ul").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('stop-animation');
    $(this).stop(false, false);
  }, function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('stop-animation');
    AnimateCarousel();
  });
});

function AnimateCarousel(){
  var $ul = $(".carousel").children('ul');
  var time = 1500;
  $ul.animate({
    left: -210
  }, time, 'linear', function(){
    $ul.append($ul.children('li:first-child'));
    $ul.css({left: 0});
    if (!$ul.is('.stop-animation')) {
      AnimateCarousel();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.carousel ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.tst1 {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 5000ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 5000ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 5000ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 5000ms ease;
  transition: all 5000ms ease;
}

.carousel li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 4px;  /*   row added  */
}

.carousel li:hover > div {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="carousel">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_66223.png" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.shinyshiny.tv/asus-android-smartphone-thumb-200x200.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div></li>
        <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/Little_island_colour_logo_200x200.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div></li>
        <li><img src="http://duncanlock.net/images/posts/better-figures-images-plugin-for-pelican/dummy-200x200.png" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div></li>

        <li><img src="http://s1.dmcdn.net/CZC2w/200x200-qyf.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div></li>
        <li><img src="http://s1.dmcdn.net/DngOt/200x200-nZB.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="tst1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 30px; bottom: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
                View Profile
            </div></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I will test it out. Thank you. Any idea on the Pause on hover?

Comment: that didn't fix the issue by the way. If you replace the placeholder image with different image.... it will show you. :9

Comment: http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_66223.png
http://www.shinyshiny.tv/asus-android-smartphone-thumb-200x200.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/Little_island_colour_logo_200x200.jpg
http://duncanlock.net/images/posts/better-figures-images-plugin-for-pelican/dummy-200x200.png
http://s1.dmcdn.net/CZC2w/200x200-qyf.jpg
https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR7kVtJRpO-7K_ePeOfT8_SV2a5fwOZx3MUSk42Acef1p76jRne
http://s1.dmcdn.net/DngOt/200x200-nZB.jpg
http://wpeden.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/verse-200x200.png

You can use all of them and check.

Comment: They are all 200x200 and different images to get a better understanding. Thanks

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge  Snippet updated. Fixed my bug. Added: pause on mouse over and continue on mouse out. Could you try and let me know? Thank you

Comment: Thank you. I tried out your code, however, can it not "snap" into place and just pause instead? https://jsfiddle.net/v844jzuw/.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge it's up to the .stop(true, true): the first is for clearQueue , and the second for  jumpToEnd.  In any case now the  "jumps to the right a little" is fixed and clarified. For this other problem you may adjust the stop(value, value) like you need. Thanks in any case for sharing.

Comment: What did you do? Wow... perfect!

Comment: I see, you used `false` instead of `true. :)

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I explained you. It's up on how you use the stop:  for details see [jQuery stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/). Is it all ok now?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the jump, change the last section of your code to the following:

```
$ul.stop().animate({
            left: -200
        }, time, 'linear', function(){
            $ul.append($ul.children('li:first-child'));
            $ul.css({left: 4});
    AnimateCarousel();
        });
```